# How to pass a variable within `<td>` tags?

Tags: jquery, html, tags

I'm brand new to jQuery. I basically want to pass a `<select>` dropdown with 20 options into a `<td>` and then add it to a variable called cols.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var counter = 1;
    $("#addrow").on("click", function () {
        if (counter < 16) {
            var newRow = $("<tr>");
            var cols = "";
            var selectList = "<select name="itemQuantity' + counter + '">";
            for (var x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
                selectList += "<option>" + x + "</option>";
            }
            selectList += "</select>";
            cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="itemName' + counter + '"/></td>';
            cols += '<td>selectList</td>';
            cols += '<td><input type="button" class="ibtnDel btn btn-md btn-danger " value="Delete"></td>';
            newRow.append(cols);
            $("table.order-list").append(newRow);
            counter++;
        }
    });

    $("table.order-list").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function (event) {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        counter -= 1
    });

});
```

I basically want the end result to be able to generate lines exactly like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHScP.jpg every time I press "Add Item". There is currently some kind of mistake with the line: `cols += '<td>selectList</td>'` You can see the logic of what I'm trying to accomplish. How can I properly pass the variable selectList here?

Comment: You might consider using consistent indentation when writing code - it'll make reading and debugging it much easier, not only for potential answerers, but for you as well, when we can all see the `{` `}` blocks and their nesting level at a glance, rather than having to carefully pick through each line just to pick up on the logical paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the below lines:

```
var selectList = "<select name="itemQuantity' + counter + '">";
cols += '<td>selectList</td>';
```

To

```
var selectList = "<select name='itemQuantity ' + counter + ' '>";
cols += '<td>' + selectList + '</td>';
```

Comment: thanks, that's one error fixed but I'm still getting this when I click "Add Item": https://i.imgur.com/qCD3DgH.jpg

Comment: YES, this works. Thank you so much. Unfortunately I am brand new and it won't let me upvote you I think.
So whenever I pass a variable like this, I must include the + on each side?

I'll go back and upvote you once I have 15 reputation and can do it.